# How to analyse program's memory usage in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, memory-management

Is there a way to check what memory has been allocated to in a program coded in VS 2010?
I've been noticing that a recent program I've been making keeps using more and more memory over time without releasing any.

Also, are there any articles on code design that teaches you good memory management? I seem to be searching the wrong terms on google as I keep getting useless results.

Answer (score 6):

There are commercial tools such as [ANTS Memory Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [.NET Memory Profiler](https://memprofiler.com/) or [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/). Secondly, take a look at [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/november/clr-inside-out-investigating-memory-issues). Lastly, Maoni Stephens has many blog posts on garbage collection and memory management in .NET. They are all linked [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140827204246/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dougste/archive/2010/02/18/an-index-to-maoni-s-blog-posts-about-the-gc.aspx).