# How to know the memory usage in C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a C++ program running by Visual Studio 2010, how can i monitor the the memory usage of my program? Does there exist simple API, such as i can call `clock_t start1` and `start1 = clock();` to monitor the time usage of my program. Thanks:)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/282194/964225

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory management is not an easy problem like timing, and it is definitely more complicated to track.

I recommend looking at other similar StackOverflow posts to get started:

[How to analyse program's memory usage in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213323/how-to-analyse-programs-memory-usage-in-visual-studio-2010)

[How do you detect/avoid Memory leaks in your (Unmanaged) code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627/how-do-you-detect-avoid-memory-leaks-in-your-unmanaged-code)

[track C++ memory allocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910172/track-c-memory-allocations)

These should help you solve whatever your specific memory-related problem is, whether it's looking for memory leaks, overwriting the end of an allocated buffer, or simply tracking how much memory you've allocated.